# Prove that a function whose derivative is bounded by M is bounded by Mx

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck on this particular problem:

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ which is differentiable on >$(0,\infty)$. If $f(0)=0$ and $\left| f'(x)\right| \leq M$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$, then prove that $\left| f(x) \right| \leq M\, x$ on $[0,\infty)$.

The question is part of the section discussing the Intermediate Value theorem for derivatives. I've considered setting it up this way:

\begin{equation}
\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} = f'(c) \leq M \\
f(x)-f(y) = f'(c) (x-y) \leq M (x-y)
\end{equation}

But this is the point at which I'm getting stuck. I guess, what I'm stuck at is the $f(x) \leq M\,x$ part, since the intermediate value theorem only gives me information about the a point in an interval having a certain value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you used the mean value theorem. Let $y=0$, stick some absolute value signs on it, and be done with it.

Comment: Wow, I should have noticed that. Thanks.

Comment: It's okay -- probably just tired, no?